# What questions are independent from the axiom of constructibility?

Tags: set-theory

Wikipedia gives a list of [statements true in L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statements_true_in_L) which would be true also for set theory if the axiom of constructibility (V=L) holds. However I wonder about the converse: Are there any important open axioms/hypotheses in ZFC that would *not* be settled by the axiom of constructibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people consider $V=L$ to be "practically complete" in the sense that it really decides most of what we care about.

The simplest examples that $V=L$ cannot decide are statements exceeding the consistency strength of $\sf ZFC$. For example:

1. There exists an inaccessible cardinal.
2. There is a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$.
3. $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$.

Comment: (Note the decreasing order of consistency! :-))

Comment: What does Con(ZFC) mean?

Comment: That $\sf ZFC$ is consistent. it's a statement about the natural numbers, of course.

Answer (score 5):

There is a paper entitled *On the necessary use of abstract set theory* by Harvey Friedman (Advances in Mathematics, vol.41, no.3, pp.209-280, [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(81)90021-9)), in which he shows that some combinatorial propositions about Borel functions are independent of $ZFC+V=L$.